# Proof for no positive real roots

Tags: quadratics

Prove that $x^6$ + $x^4$ +$x^2$+ $x$ +  $3$ has no positive real roots.

My attempt:
I couldn't really think of a way to do this. I have looked at a similar problem but it had a cubic equation where you assign variables to the roots and use them to prove, but that method becomes tedious if you have to do it for this equation.

Answer (score 7):

If $x$ is positive then $x^2,x^4,x^6$ are also positive so $$x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 3 \ge 3.$$

Comment: Great answer!!!!!!